# How to pass MongoDB collection name as a parameter to a DB connection function-Python

Tags: python, mongodb

I need to write a DB connection function as ,

```
def func(col_name):
    conn = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost" , 27017)
    db   = conn.dbname.col_name
    return db
```

collection name should be passed as a parameter to the function. Above function is not working. it is working if I hard-coded the collection name in the code.
Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) to get attribute of an object by attribute name:

```
getattr(conn.dbname, col_name)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def func(col_name):
    conn = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost" , 27017)
    return conn.dbname[col_name]
```

You can do the same from the client if you want to pass in the database name:

```
def func(db_name, col_name):
    conn = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost" , 27017)
    return conn[db_name][col_name]
```